Can I inherit custom loaded functions or cmdlets in Powershell after running Enter-PSHostProcess?
In Powershell, I can use Enter-PSHostProcess to debug specific programs. Since I'm doing a lot of debugging I thought I'd write a function to save me some time. The function:
function global:Debug-MyProgram {
    Enter-PSHostProcess -Name "NameOfService"
    Get-Runspace | Where-Object{$_.Debugger.InBreakpoint} | Debug-Runspace
}

The problem is that after running Enter-PSHostProcess I no longer have access to the Debug-MyProgram function because the PSHostProcess doesn't inherit that function. The effect of this is that the Get-Runspace line is never run.
Is there a way for me to keep using custom functions after entering a PS Host process?
